# System not supporting boot screen xp and xp2

Tags: windows-xp, boot

Whenever I try to install Windows xp or xp2 on my system, my system freezes on boot screen, but it supports the boot screen of Windows Server 2003, or Windows vista. Why I'm getting this problem?

Answer (score 2):

most likely cause: your system is using a SATA controller (in RAID or AHCI mode) which is not natively supported in Windows XP.

you can set the controller mode in the BIOS to IDE or you may have to load a 3rd party controller driver via F6 when prompted.

Comment: Our office has almost reached the point of remembering to find the SATA driver *before* trying to re-install XP...